Build a spiral staircase inside a tower
These are two versions of the same tower with 5 floors
__F_     __⚑_  
|D/|     |█/|
|\_|     |\_|
|_/|     |_/|
|\D|     |\█|
|_/|     |_/|

A spiral staircase is built inside the tower. Each floor is made of three elements:

walls on each side (|)
a flat surface (_) OR a door (D or █)
stairs that lead to the next floor (/ or \)

Each floor must have 1 flat surface or door, 1 staircase, and must be enclosed within 2 walls.
A door is always present on the left at the bottom of the tower (|█/| or |D/|) and the staircase should lead to the flag at the top of the tower.
The top of the tower is a flat rooftop with a tiny flag (__⚑_ or __F_). The flag is aligned with the direction of the staircase on the last floor.
__F_     __⚑_  
|_/|     |_/|

_F__     _⚑__  
|\_|     |\_|


Stairs always lead to a flat surface or a door, so the following floors combinations are not allowed:
|_/|     |\_| 
|_/|     |\_|

Lastly, being a spiral staircase, stairs must change direction each floor. The following combinations are not allowed:
|/_|     |_\| 
|_/|     |\_|

Task
Your task is to build and print a tower based on an input representing the height of each floor, such as 2 1 2 1 1. The minimum height for a floor is 1.
Each number in the input defines the height of the current floor and ultimately how tall the tower is.
Doors should only appear if specified in in the input. Additional doors are not allowed.
A few examples:
Input: 3 2 4 1 2
_⚑__   _F__
|\_|   |\_|
|█/|   |D/|
|\█|   |\D|
|_/|   |_/|         Input: 2 1 2 1 1
|\_|   |\_|         __⚑_   __F_
|_/|   |_/|         |█/|   |D/|
|\█|   |\D|         |\█|   |\D|
|_/|   |_/|         |_/|   |_/|
|\█|   |\D|         |\█|   |\D|
|_/|   |_/|         |█/|   |D/|        Input: 1
|\_|   |\_|         |\_|   |\_|         __⚑_   __F_
|█/|   |D/|         |█/|   |D/|         |█/|   |D/|

Rules

No need for input checking
The input must contain at least 1 value/height
The input can be a sequence of characters separated by a whitespace   or an array/list/stream of integers compatible with the language
Only chose one set of characters, don't print both versions of the tower
No other characters can be used as alternatives
This is a code-golf challenge, shortest solution in bytes wins


one of your test cases for height 1 has the flag in the wrong spot. I assume it isn't legal to output doors on floors that don't need them, Mission Cleopatra-style?

Thank you fixed the mistake, and no doors should only appear on floors that need them

The inputs 1 and <empty> should print the same because the rules state that there's always a door at the bottom of the tower. I've modified the examples.

... doesn't add anything to the challenge neither does the roof, and yet it's part of the challenge...

I get what you mean now sorry, and I agree. I'll remove the example and add a rule

This challenge reminds me of this video game. :-)

05AB1E, 29 bytes
L˜Θ„_Dsè„|\ì…__Fª€Ć2Å€º2äθ}R»

Try it online or verify all test cases.
Explanation:
L           # Map each value in the (implicit) input-list to a [1,value]-ranged list
 ˜          # Flatten this list of lists
  Θ         # Check for each value whether it equals 1 (1 if 1; 0 otherwise)
   „_D      # Push string "_D"
      sè    # 0-based index the earlier 1s/0s into this
„|\ì        # Prepend "|\" before each character in the list
    …__Fª   # Append "__F" to the list
         €Ć # Enclose each string; appending its own head
2Å€    }    # Apply to every 0-based index where index%2==0:
   º        #  Mirror the current string
    2ä      #  Split it into two equal-sized parts
      θ     #  Pop and only leave the second mirrored part
        R   # Then reverse the entire list of strings
         »  # And join it by newlines
            # (after which the string is output implicitly as result)


Charcoal, 29 bytes
_F__¶Ｆ⮌⭆Ａ⭆ι§_D¬λ«Ｍ³→‖Ｔ⟦⪫||⁺ι/

Try it online! Link is to verbose version of code. Explanation:
_F__¶

Output the flag.
Ｆ⮌⭆Ａ⭆ι§_D¬λ«

Convert the list of floors into a list of Ds and _s depending on where the doors should be, and work down from the top floor.
Ｍ³→‖Ｔ

Reflect the tower so far, turning any /s into \s and vice versa as necessary.
⟦⪫||⁺ι/

Draw the next floor of the tower. This ensures that the bottom floor is always |D/|.

APL+WIN, 122 bytes
Prompts for a vector of floor heights.
m←((i←+/n←⎕),4)⍴' '⋄m[;1 4]←'|'⋄m[;2]←i⍴'_\'⋄m[;3]←i⍴'/_'⋄m[(2|d)/d←1,¯1↓1++\n;2]←'D'⋄m[(~2|d)/d;3]←'D'⋄((-2|i)⌽'_F__')⍪⊖m

Try it online! Thanks to Dyalog Classic

C (clang), 139 136 134 131 bytes
i,t;f(*a,n){for(i=t=0;i<n;)t^=a[i++]%2;for(puts(t?"__F_":"_F__");n--;)for(;a[n]--;t^=1)printf("|%s|\n",L"彜䑜⽟⽄"+!a[n]+2*t);}

Try it online!

-6 bytes thanks to ceilingcat!


Jelly,  35 34  33 bytes
ÄŻ‘Ṭ~JḂṭ;ƭ"ƊØ2jⱮṚ‘Ṡ’$1¦ị“\/|FD_”Y

Try it online!
How?
ÄŻ‘Ṭ~JḂṭ;ƭ"ƊØ2jⱮṚ‘Ṡ’$1¦ị“\/|FD_”Y - Link: list of floor heights, H
Ä                                 - cumulative sums of {H}
 Ż                                - prefix {that} with a zero
  ‘                               - increment
   Ṭ                              - untruth -> list of door/floor bits
    ~                             - bitwise not of {that} (vectorises)
                                      -> -2 for doors (D); -1 for floor (_)
           Ɗ                      - last three links as a monad -f(X=that):
     J                            -   [1..length(X)]
      Ḃ                           -   mod two -> [1,0,1,0,...]
                                       (representing "\/\/...")
          "                       -   zip {that} and {X} with: 
         ƭ                        -     alternate between:
       ṭ                          -       tack
        ;                         -       concatenate
            Ø2jⱮ                  - [2,2] joined with each of those
                                     (representing the "||")
                Ṛ                 - reverse
                 ‘                - increment (vectorises)
                                     (now -1:D 0:_ 1:\ 2:/ 3:|
                                      but the roof is like any other level)
                     1¦           - apply to the first (the roof):
                  Ṡ’$             -   sign and then decrement
                                     -> takes -1 (D) to -2 (F),
                                        and 1,2,3 (\/|) to 0 (_)
                       ị“\/|FD_”  - index (1-indexed & modular) into "\/|FD_"
                                Y - join with newline characters


JavaScript (ES6), 91 bytes
f=(a,r,c=([h,...a]=a,"D"))=>h--?f(a,!r,"_")+`
|${r?"\\"+c:c+"/"}|`:h?f(a,r):r?`__F_`:`_F__`

Try it online!
Commented
f = (              // f is a recursive function taking:
  a,               //   a[] = input array
  r,               //   r = a flag that is truthy when the door or the
                   //       flat surface must appear on the right
  c = (            //   c = initialized to 'D', then set to '_'
    [h, ...a] = a, //   h = height of current floor, extracted from a[]
    "D"            //       when f is called with c undefined
  )                //
) =>               //
h-- ?              // if h is defined and not 0 (decrement it afterwards):
  f(a, !r, "_") +  //   do a recursive call with r inverted and c = '_'
  `\n|${           //   append a new line and a '|' followed by:
    r ? "\\" + c   //     either '\' and c if r is truthy
      : c + "/"    //     or c and '/' if r is falsy
  }|`              //   append another '|'
:                  // else:
  h ?              //   if h is not NaN:
    f(a, r)        //     do a recursive call for the next floor
                   //     with r unchanged and c undefined
  :                //   else (end of recursion):
    r ? `__F_`     //     append the roof with the flag on the right ...
      : `_F__`     //     ... or on the left, according to r


Vyxal, 30 27 bytes
ʁ†f‛_Dİv`|Π/|`‛_F4eJ‡øṀ∷ẇṘ⁋

Try it Online! -3 bytes inspired by Kevin Cruijssen's 05AB1E answer.
ʁ                           # For each, range from 0 to n-1
 †                          # Logical NOT of each, giving 1s as first items in subarrays
  f                         # Flatten, giving a list of 0/1 bits representing doors/floors
      İ                     # And map 0, 1 to
   ‛_D                      # _, D
       v`|Π/|`              # Insert each into "|[char]/|" (this is legitimately the shortest way I could find to do this)
                   J        # And append
              ‛_F4e         # "_F__"
                    ‡---ẇ   # To every other line
                     øṀ     # Mirror it, flipping slashes,
                       ∷    # And take the second half, flipping it vertically
                         Ṙ⁋ # Reverse the result and join by newlines


Python 3.8 (pre-release), 171 133 bytes
Probably can be made shorter, this is my first submission, and I'm surprised I could get it this short! I couldn't figure out how to squish it all into one line and a lambda function with less bytes. I'm open to improvements!
def T(a):
 o=[n for i in a.split()for n in["|D/|"]+(int(i)-1)*["|_/|"]]+["_F__"]
 print(*[o[i][::1-(l:=i%2)*2].replace(l*'/',l*'\\')for i in range(len(o))][::-1],sep="\n")

Try it online!
Shorter code from comments:
lambda a:[print(v[::i%2*2-1].replace(i%2*'\\',i%2*'/'))for i,v in enumerate(["_F__"]+[f"|{c}\|"for i in a[::-1]for c in~-i*"_"+"D"])]

Try it online!

Welcome to Code Golf, and nice first answer! Here's 146 bytes with some rearrangements and taking input as a list of integers.

Actually 140 bytes

actually 134

133 bytes

@emanresuA the bottom floor should always be |D/|

AWK, 140 bytes
{for(b=1;++i<=NF;){a[b]=b%2?"|█/|":"|\\█|"
for(j=0;++j<=$i;)a[++b]=b%2?"|\\_|":"|_/|"}a[b]=b%2?"_⚑__":"__⚑_"
for(;b>0;)print a[b--]}

Try it online!
